# Sed move text to beginning of line?

Tags: bash, sed

I have a variable with the contents "eth0 eth1 bond0", is there a way using sed or a similar tool to move anything matching `bond.*` to the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using nothing but Bash:

```
$ var="eth0 eth1 bond0"
$ [[ $var =~ (.*)\ (bond.*) ]]
$ var="${BASH_REMATCH[2]} ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
$ echo "$var"
bond0 eth0 eth1
```

**Edit:**

This version handles multiple occurrences of "bond" anywhere within the string:

```
var="eth0 bond0 eth1 bond1 eth2 bond2"
for word in $var
do
    if [[ $word =~ bond ]]
    then
        begin+="$word "
    else
        end+="$word "
    fi
done
var="$begin$end"
var="${var%* }"    # if you need to strip the trailing space
echo "$var"
```

Output:

```
bond0 bond1 bond2 eth0 eth1 eth2
```

Edit 2:

Here is a `sed` version that is specific to the string "bond" followed by one or more digits rather than allowing any word that begins with "b":

```
$ echo "eth0 bond0 eth1 bond1 eth2 bond2" | 
sed 's/\<bond[[:digit:]]\+/\n&\n/g; s/ //g; :a; s/\(.*\)\n\(bond[[:digit:]]\+\)/\2 \1/;ta; s/\n/ /g'
bond0 bond1 bond2 eth0 eth1 eth2
```

Comment: thank you, it's useful to have both scenarios covered, single and multiple instance of bond.* :)

Answer (score 3):

you can also use awk

```
echo "eth0 bond1 eth1 bond0 eth2 bond2" | awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        if($i~/bond/){a[++d]=$i}
        else{b[++e]=$i}
}END{
    for(i=1;i<=d;i++){
        printf a[i]" "
    }
    for(i=1;i<=e;i++){
        printf b[i]" "
    }
}'
```

output

```
$ ./shell.sh
bond1 bond0 bond2 eth0 eth1 eth2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
echo "eth0 bond0 eth1 bond1 eth2 bond2" | sed ':a;s/\<\([^b]*\) \(b.*\)/\2 \1/g;ta'
bond0 bond1 bond2 eth0 eth1 eth2
```

This works by moving words not begining with `b` behind words that do.